# Upper bound for $\int_{|u|\ge 1} |u|^{-n-2a} \, du$ which does not depend on $a$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

Let $n\in\mathbb{N}, n\ge 2$ and let $0<a<b\le 1$. I am trying to find an upper bound for the integral

$$\int_{|u|\ge 1} |u|^{-n-2a} \, du$$

where the integral is done over $\mathbb{R}^n$ outside the unit ball $\mathbf{B}^n$.
I am seeking an upper bound independent on $a$ (but it would be fine if the constant depend on $b$).

My attempt is:
$$\int_{|u|\ge 1} |u|^{-n-2a} \, du =\int_1^{+\infty}\int_{\partial B_1} \rho^{-n-2a+n-1} d\square d\rho = c \int_1^{+\infty} \rho^{-1-2a} d\rho =-\frac{1}{2a}[\rho^{-2a}]_1^{+\infty} = \frac{1}{2a},$$
where $c>0$ denotes a constant depending on the measure of $\partial B_1$.

There is any chance to get an upper bound which does not depend on $a$?
Clearly, I do not want to make any more assumptions about $a$ and/or $b$ (e.g. is clear that $\frac{1}{2a}<1$ if $a$ if $a\in (1/2, b)$ but I do not want to add any more condition like that).

Comment: @NinadMunshi, what do you mean by domain of the integral?

Comment: I am integrating over $|u|\ge 1$, outside the $n$-dimensional sphere of radius $1$.

Comment: Then please edit your post to reflect the full information. Not once did you say $|u|\geq 1$ was embedded in $\Bbb{R}^n$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your evaluation of the integral
$$ \int_{|u|\geq1} |u|^{-n-2a} du = c\cdot\frac{1}{2a},$$

where $c$ is the area of the $n-1$ dimensional sphere, is exact.

Hence, you can make it diverge by taking $a\rightarrow 0$, which means that the only upper bound without any dependence on $a$ should be $\infty$.

Comment: Hyeongmuk LIM, thank you for your answer. Could you please integrate it by providing an example with an upper bound involving $b$ instead than $\infty$? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Unfortunately, that is impossible; for if $f(b)<\infty$ is such a bound, you can make the integral larger than $f(b)$ by taking $a$ as small as you need. This is the point of my answer.